# How to create a two-step sign-up process with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

For example, at Twitter.com, the user can input their full name, email, and password to 'sign up' on the homepage.. which then redirects to another sign-up page where he/she can further input more details (username, accept T&C etc.)

How would one go about splitting the signup process into two pages or more?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a gem for this https://github.com/schneems/wicked. Not sure how well it integrates with devise though.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try thinking of it more as a first-page signup (create action), second-page add more info (edit action).

You can make the first page the true sign up page, where they enter full name, email, and password.  After submitting (and auto-signing in), they would get redirected to a modified edit page, where they can add additional information to their account (username, accept T&C, etc..).  This way you can stick within CRUD.